# Difference in results of permutation tests through coin::oneway.test and resample::permutationTest2

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, permutation-test

I'm trying to run a same permutation test for the null hypothesis of no difference between means with the `coin` and `resample` R packages. However, I get quite different p-values, which I was not expecting.

Should the two packages provide such different p-values? Am I performing the same test in the two packages?

My minimal reprex:

```r
library(coin)
library(resample)
set.seed(42)

pvalue(oneway_test(extra ~ group,
            data = sleep,
            distribution = approximate(nresample = 9999)))
#> [1] 0.08230823

permutationTest2(sleep, mean(extra), as.factor(group))$stats$PValue
#> [1] 0.0106
```

Comment: oneway.test is from stats and it is not a permutation based test. You should use coin::oneway_test, but this won't answer your question

Comment: one problem is that coin uses Fisher-Pitman permutation test which does not test the difference between means. However, using 
`library(wPerm); perm.ind.loc(sleep$extra, sleep$group, mean)` I also get different results

Comment: thank you for pointing the code mistake, @rep_ho. I've corrected to coin::oneway_test